# How to scroll All Search Hashtag result in instagram With SELENIUM

Tags: selenium-webdriver, search, scroll, instagram, hashtag

I want to get all the users using #book from the Instagram site, but I can only get one page of results,
If there are about 2000 pages.

This code does not work properly :

```
EOS = wd.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
while True:
    wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
    sleep(7)
    my_scroll = wd.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
    print (my_scroll)
    if my_scroll == EOS:
       break
    EOS = my_scroll
```

Comment: "This code does not work properly" what happens?